# How to pass username and password of REST API in windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

```
   public void Execute()       
   {          
        if(this.OnPreExecute!=null)
        {
            this.OnPreExecute();
        }

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(this.Url);
        //httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
        SetBasicAuthHeader(httpWebRequest, userName, password);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";           

        httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(OnGetResponseCompleted, httpWebRequest);
    }

    public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest httpWebRequest, String userName, String password)
    {            
        string authInfo = userName + ":" + password;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(authInfo));
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic" + authInfo;
    }
```

consider that i'm having username as admin and password as 3. How would i have to pass those values.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var   uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "userName", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName));
        postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "password", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password));

        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();
        webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks who responsed for this question for spending your precious time.

you just have to pass the username credentials method along with that API.Just like as follows,

i used Username as manoj and Password as 3

httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("manoj", "3");